# Insert decimal point into specific position

Tags: php, numbers, decimal-point

Currently have a number stored in a variable that is returned from an API call. I wish to insert a decimal point into this number before it's returned the the user.

I have tried exploding it into a list however, no luck.

```
$cTotal = 32275247631
```

I wish this variable to become:

```
$cTotal = 32.275247631
```

Comment: you want dot in third position always?

Comment: The question is not clear. Does the external API returns the values multiplied by some big power of 10? (`32275247631 == 32.275247631 * 10^9) What's the rule to decide the insertion point?

Comment: Preferable I'd wish it to by dynamic to the length of the number but I should be able to do that when someone tells me why I am being dumb and cannot get the decimal point to appear.

The API (a total of multiple bitcoin wallets) returns the value as seen in cTotal nothing more.

Comment: In api itself should return with dot

Comment: Example:
https://blockchain.info/q/getreceivedbyaddress/1Hs4YTJHLLTKyJyeeAgZKu3zzJbpEMgxSq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with php's [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

```
<?php
$num = 123456789;
$newstr = substr_replace($num, ".", 2, 0);
echo $newstr; // returns 12.3456789
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did try this too however it places the point at the end of the number:

"32460692771."

Comment: I agree, it works standalone but when I implement this into my code it just places the point at the end. Trying to figure it out now

Comment: Then there could be some modification is being done by existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question i understood this.Try like below:

```
$cTotal = 32275247631;
echo substr_replace( $cTotal, '.', 2, 0 );
```

For more information check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr_replace.asp)

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: I did try this too however it places the point at the end of the number: "32460692771."

Comment: I agree, it works standalone but when I implement this into my code it just places the point at the end. Trying to figure it out now.

Answer (score 1):

To insert decimal after n positions just divide number by 10^n.

```
    $cTotal = 32275247631;
    $position = 9;
    $cTotal = $cTotal/pow(10,$position);
    echo $cTotal;
```